# Asp.net mvc doesn't post to the server form data from Html.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have such code in my form

```
@foreach (var option in Model.Options)
{
    @Html.Action("GetQuestionOption", new { optionId = option.Id })
}
```

And here are the controller and partial view

```
public ActionResult GetQuestionOption(int? optionId = null)
{
    var option = optionId.HasValue ? UnitOfWork.OptionRepository.GetById(optionId.Value) : new QuestionOption();
    return PartialView("_Option", option);
 }
```

Partial View

```
@model QuestionOption

<div class="option-box">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OptionText)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OptionText)
    </div>
</div>
```

However when I submit my form this data doesn't posted to the server and Options are always null. I guess this is not mapped to the Options. How can I make this to work?

P.S. I'm also adding options with javascript there

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Contr/GetQuestionOption",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#options").append(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: where are you declaring data option 'data:' in ajax request?

Comment: Have you able to hit the controller on calling the Ajax

Comment: Where is you submit button? Can you provide more code

Comment: People, all the code needed is here. Html.Action is generating option boxes. BUT it is not mapped to the model Options property. This is the question, don't look at submit button or at data attribute of ajax request...

Comment: Please show us the code which you have written to where to load the partial view.

Comment: _People all the code needed is here._ You haven't even included the method your posting back to!! I assume your trying to post back a collection in which case you cant use partial views (at least not like that)

Answer (score 0):

Your Partial View, You have to put fields inside Form, and give Id

```
     @model QuestionOption

    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetQuestionOption", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myId" }))
    {  
    <div class="option-box">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OptionText)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OptionText)
        </div>
    </div>
<input id="postForm" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
    }
```

Ajax Request:

```
$('#postForm').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
data: $('#myId').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Contr/GetQuestionOption",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#options").append(data);
                }
            });

});
```